# AS3: Load / Read text file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been trying to load a text file for hours but I'm still stucked. The text file called *Pi.txt* containing a lot of digits of the Pi number. So I wrote a class called *PiLoader* to load the file:

```
package Pi
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class PiLoader
    {
        private static var piURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../src/Pi/Pi.txt");
        private static var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(piURL);
        private static var pi:String;

        public function PiLoader() {}

        public static function getPi():String {
            textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
            return pi;
        }

        private static function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
            pi = loader.data;
        }

    }

}
```

In *Main.as*, I traced the 3 first digits of the Pi number:

```
package Action 
{
        import flash.display.Sprite;

        import Pi.PiLoader;

        public class Main extends Sprite
        {

            public function Main() 
            {
            trace(PiLoader.getPi().substring(0, 4));
            }

        }

}
```

But I always get this: *Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference*. I found out that the function *onLoaded()* in the *PiLoader* class will never be called. That's why I get that error. 
Need your help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Error #1009` is fired because your `PiLoader` is null, that's normal. But here I want discuss the method used. You should know that `URLLoader.load()`, which you did not call in your code, is an asynchronous operation, so you should wait until the `Event.COMPLETE` is fired to use the returned data. In this case, you can use a callback like this :

**Main.as :**

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var pi_loader:PiLoader;

        public function Main() {

            pi_loader = new PiLoader();
            pi_loader.getPi(show_pi);

        }

        // your function called only when data is loaded inside the PiLoader
        private function show_pi(pi:String) {

            trace(pi.substring(0, 3));

        }

    }
}
```

**PiLoader.as :**

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class PiLoader {

        private static var piURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest('path_to_file.txt');
        private static var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(piURL);

        public function PiLoader() {
        }

        public function getPi(callback:Function):void {

            textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
            function onLoaded(e:Event):void {

                // run our function and give it data
                callback(e.target.data);

            }
            textLoader.load(piURL);

        }

    }

}
```

Hope that can help you.